# SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need the info regarding the SQL Server 2000 software along with price list n the procedure of purchasing it...

Answer (score 2):

You can not buy SQL Server 2000 any longer.  Mainstream support for it ended 04/08/2008, nor would you want to given the extra features in SQL Server 2008

[End of Mainstream support for SQL Server 2005 SP1 and SQL Server 2000 SP4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2008/02/15/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2005-sp1-and-sql-server-2000-sp4.aspx)